# Facebook API for iPhone: including html link in the post

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink

I'm using the Facebook API on an iPhone application but can't figure out how to include a clickable link in my the description of my post. Tried to put the `<a href....> </a>` in it but it's removed from the message.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Hey!! there is no way to give a clickable link in the description part but you can achieve the same thing by using the "properties" attribute of the attachment, following links will be helpful : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments and multiple properties for facebook feed publishing attachment